# How can I retain extra/multiple spaces when I convert HTML to Dataframe using pandas pd.read_html()?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to convert `HTML` to Dataframe using `pd.read_html` but it automatically removes the multiple spaces in between the text.

For Example:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>35</td>
   <td>Juan  Cruz</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>23</td>
   <td>Philip   Philips</td>
</tr>
```

Expected Output:

```
[  0             1
   35       Juan  Cruz
   23       Philip   Philips]
```

Actual Output:

```
[  0             1
   35        Juan Cruz
   23        Philip Philips]
```

Any recommendation to keep extra spaces?

I tried to search for the alternative with the same output, but I can't find one. I also tried to change the space to   then convert but it didn't work, and it takes a lot of time if I convert every space into tokenize character and convert it back. Any recommendation, can I use some regex on this problem or any alternative solution?

Comment: The was a pull request to add an option for this but it went stale/was closed due to a lack of tests: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/39925

Answer (score 2):

You can override [`_remove_whitespace`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/37ea63d540fd27274cad6585082c91b1283f963d/pandas/io/html.py#L89) function:

```
def _remove_whitespace(s, regex=None):
    return s.strip()
pd.io.html._remove_whitespace = _remove_whitespace
```

Output:

```
>>> pd.read_html(html)

[    0                 1
 0  35        Juan  Cruz
 1  23  Philip   Philips]
```

Comment: Always thinking outside the box, +1 ;)

Comment: This is my only added value on Pandas :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can tell pandas to keep those extra *whitespaces*.

As a workaround, you can use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) :

```py
#pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
​
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
​
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[cell.get_text() for cell in row.find_all("td")] for row in soup.find_all("tr")]
)
```

​
Ouptut :

```py
print(df)

    0                 1
0  35        Juan  Cruz
1  23  Philip   Philips
```